# How do I pass GslHeader argument to clang-tidy while using -fix option?

Tags: clang, clang-tidy

I couldn't find sample code for a clang-tidy command line for fixing the  following error:

```
[archlinux@thinkpad fizzbuzz]$ clang-tidy fizzbuzz2.cpp -checks=cppcoreguidelines-pro-bounds-constant-array-index
5 warnings generated.
fizzbuzz2.cpp:21:18: warning: do not use array subscript when the index is not an integer constant expression; use gsl::at() instead [cppcoreguidelines-pro-bounds-constant-array-index]
    std::cout << arr[index] << std::endl;
                 ^
Suppressed 4 warnings (4 in non-user code).
Use -header-filter=.* to display errors from all non-system headers. Use -system-headers to display errors from system headers as well.
[archlinux@thinkpad fizzbuzz]$
```

I just want to find out how I can get clang-tidy to fix this automatically. If not, how should I use `gsl::at()` to fix this? The clang-tidy documentation says the following:

```
cppcoreguidelines-pro-bounds-constant-array-index

This check flags all array subscript expressions on static arrays and std::arrays that either do not have a constant integer expression index or are out of bounds (for std::array). For out-of-bounds checking of static arrays, see the -Warray-bounds Clang diagnostic.

This rule is part of the “Bounds safety” profile of the C++ Core Guidelines, see https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Pro-bounds-arrayindex.
Options

GslHeader

    The check can generate fixes after this option has been set to the name of the include file that contains gsl::at(), e.g. “gsl/gsl.h”.

IncludeStyle

    A string specifying which include-style is used, llvm or google. Default is llvm.
```

I found the `gsl::at()` subroutine in `<gsl/gsl_util>`. How do I tell clang-tidy to use it to fix my warning?

Edit: I looked at the config string and found the solution to this:

On running:

`clang-tidy fizzbuzz2.cpp -checks=cppcoreguidelines-pro-bounds-constant-array-index -dump-config`

I got some hints towards the solution

`clang-tidy fizzbuzz2.cpp -checks=cppcoreguidelines-pro-bounds-constant-array-index -config="{CheckOptions: [{key: cppcoreguidelines-pro-bounds-constant-array-index.GslHeader, value: gsl/gsl_util}]}" -fix`

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I looked at the config string and found the solution to this:

On running:

```
clang-tidy fizzbuzz2.cpp -checks=cppcoreguidelines-pro-bounds-constant-array-index -dump-config
```

I got some hints towards the solution

```
clang-tidy fizzbuzz2.cpp -checks=cppcoreguidelines-pro-bounds-constant-array-index -config="{CheckOptions: [{key: cppcoreguidelines-pro-bounds-constant-array-index.GslHeader, value: gsl/gsl_util}]}" -fix
```